# Changing System.Drawing.Bitmap.Palette

Tags: c#, .net, system.drawing, system.drawing.imaging

I have a TIFF file in memory, which I obtained by a variant of the following code:

```
Image myImage = Image.FromFile("somefile.tiff");
```

Currently, myImage.Palette only returns two colors, black and white.  I would like to expand this to include the entire color spectrum. However, myImage.Palette does not have a function to add additional colors.

Can someone help give my TIFFs some color?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use the [Clone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141944.aspx) method to clone the bitmap to `Format8bppIndexed`